# Tell me whats wrong with this function?

Tags: function, python-3.x

```
def compute_invigilated_mark():

    """Prints given name and family name with overall score""" 

    test = 0.15

    exam = 0.60    

    first_name = input("Given names(s)? ")

    last_name = input("Family name? ")

    both_names = last_name.upper() + "," + first_name.title()

    new_test_percent = float(input("Test percent? ")) * test

    new_exam_percent = float(input("Exam percent? ")) * exam

    overall_percent = new_test_percent + new_exam_percent

    end_result = overall_percent / (exam + test)

    print(both_names + end_result)

compute_invigilated_mark()
```

I want to get the end result of, For example: `Bourne, Jason: 66.0`

The rrror message:

> builtins.TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly.

NB: I spaced it out like this so you could read it easier :).

Comment: The spacing is the opposite of helpful

Answer (score 1):

`both_names` is a string and `end_result` is a float, yet you are trying to add\concat them together (`print(both_names + end_result)`).

You should  convert `end_result` to a string:

`print(both_names + str(end_result))`

Comment: thanks :) the most simple things always catch me out :P